# Overwritte image in webcontent

Tags: struts2

I am developing struts2 application.
In my application I am uploading profile image with user name.
When user upload image first time it works fine but when user upload new image old image is not overwritten with new image it shows old image only
Please suggest solution for this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Did you refresh the page after, or what did you code to show the images?

Comment: Yes I refresh the page after reload. To show image I used the below code <img src:"<s:property value="obj2.photo"/>"/>

Comment: What is this `obj2.photo`?

Comment: I am using DTO DAO in this application I setting photo value in DAO Class like this obj2.setString(rs.getString("photo"));

Comment: What is a string is it a filepath or url, or may be it's an encoded image?

Comment: It is file path i setting in obj2.photo retrieved from database

Comment: how it could show at first time? The first time before upload or after upload?

Comment: Before upload I change the name to user name then store it into folder but when user upload again new image it does not replace old image

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't replace? Do you have a database constraint or your transaction doesn't commit?

Comment: Db store only path there is no such constraints

Comment: You need to show the code for uploading and displaying images, also prove that the image data is saved and retrieved from the database correctly.

Comment: Problem is now solved there is permission issue with overwriting images in folder

Comment: How could anyone imagine that you had *permission issue with overwriting images in folder*? Post errors stacktrace and code related to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store uploadable artifacts within the web app itself.

1. You'll probably lose it when you redeploy
2. If you deploy as a WAR you *can't* write to the web app contents

Store photos in an external location, preferably a configurable one, or use a service.

Comment: When i store images outside project jsp does not display image

Comment: If store outside images how should i retrieve image

Comment: Via a `"stream"` result, or configure your server to use the image directory as an asset directory.